# In win32 programming, how do I draw a rectangle anywhere on the screen (outside my program)?

Tags: windows, winapi, drawing

I work in application testing team. I've been assigned a task to write a win32 application that takes screenshots of rectangular sections of the screen. This involves selecting the part of the screen to take screenshot of.

What I can't figure out is how do I draw a rectangle anywhere on the screen, which would be the rectangular area to take screenshot of. I've seen other applications do it but I can't find tutorials on how to do this exactly.

I know how to draw rectangles in my own application (`BeginPaint` and `Rectangle` win32 functions), but how do I draw a rectangle anywhere on the screen?

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way around.  Make the screenshot first.

Comment: @HansPassant and then what?

Comment: Then you can display that bitmap in a full screen borderless window and you can draw rectangles as you like.  Easy peasy.

Comment: I thought so, but what if the user changes his or her mind about taking the screenshot? Then I'd have that bitmap displayed over the screen, and he'd think that the screen has frozen...

Comment: What if he changes his mind in your original scenario?  Same way.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it works because I don't know when a user would change his mind. He'd just have a screenshot overlayed over the real screen and think the screen froze.

Answer (score 7):

- Create a top-level window the same size as the size of the screen, and set the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style
- Call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` and set the transparent color to `RGB(255,0,255)`.
- Completely fill your window with the transparent color
- Draw your rectangle in another color over the top of it

**EDIT:**

This function uses `UpdateLayeredWindow` to achieve the same result. I haven't actually tested it but it compiles ok :)

```
void DrawRectangleOnTransparent(HWND hWnd, const RECT& rc)
{
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    if (hDC)
    {
        RECT rcClient;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

        BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
        bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
        bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = rcClient.right;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -rcClient.bottom;

        LPVOID pBits;
        HBITMAP hBmpSource = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pBits, 0, 0);
        if (hBmpSource)
        {
            HDC hDCSource = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
            if (hDCSource)
            {
                // fill the background in red
                HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hDCSource, hBmpSource);
                HBRUSH hBsh = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,255));
                FillRect(hDCSource, &rcClient, hBsh);
                DeleteObject(hBsh);

                // draw the rectangle in black
                HGDIOBJ hOldBsh = SelectObject(hDCSource, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
                HGDIOBJ hOldPen = SelectObject(hDCSource, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0,0,0)));
                Rectangle(hDCSource, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
                DeleteObject(SelectObject(hDCSource, hOldPen));
                SelectObject(hDCSource, hOldBsh);

                GdiFlush();

                // fix up the alpha channel
                DWORD* pPixel = reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(pBits);
                for (int y = 0; y < rcClient.bottom; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < rcClient.right; x++, pPixel++)
                    {
                        if ((*pPixel & 0x00ff0000) == 0x00ff0000)
                            *pPixel |= 0x01000000; // transparent
                        else
                            *pPixel |= 0xff000000; // solid
                    }
                }

                // Update the layered window
                POINT pt = { 0 };
                BLENDFUNCTION bf = { AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA };
                UpdateLayeredWindow(hWnd, hDC, NULL, NULL, hDCSource, &pt, 0, &bf, ULW_ALPHA);

                SelectObject(hDCSource, hOldBmp);
                DeleteDC(hDCSource);
            }
            DeleteObject(hBmpSource);
        }
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I implemented this but I've run into a problem. When I completely fill my window with the transparent color it becomes "physically transparent" - meaning that if I click inside of the transparent area, the window behind the transparent window gets focus (the click goes through to the background window, so to say).  I'm trying to draw a rectangle from mouse coordinates but I can't do it because I'm no longer able to focus on the window. Do you've more ideas about this?

Comment: Set your transparency to 1, not 0. Your window will still look transparent, but it will get mouse events.

Comment: Jonathan, it doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing it correctly? I assume transparency 1 is 255 (non-transparent). I'm filling my window with `RGB(0,0,255)` and I call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(WinHWND, RGB(0,0,255), 255, LWA_COLORKEY|LWA_ALPHA);` However the area that got pained is still letting the clicks through.

Comment: Transparency 1 is transparency 1 :) `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(WinHWND, RGB(0,0,255), 1, LWA_COLORKEY);` Note that you have to use either `LWA_COLORKEY` or `LWA_ALPHA`, not both.

Comment: Jonathan, I tried this but it doesn't appear to be working :(. I tried it with and without the `LWA_ALPHA` bit set. (I removed the bit because I couldn't find my window anymore as it was so transparent :)). My final attempt was `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(WinHWND, RGB(0,0,255), 1, LWA_COLORKEY);` This would display the window edges and I could see through the filled region, but clicking the transparent region would still bring the mouse through to the window behind it. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(WinHWND, RGB(0,0,255), 1, LWA_ALPHA);` did it! (setting `LWA_COLORKEY` bit made it not work). Now the whole window is invisible but it captures the mouse events.

Comment: I don't actually need to fill the window with any transparent color, because everything is simply invisible.

Comment: Glad you got it working! There's another way to do it which involves using `UpdateLayeredWindow`, I just wrote you a function for that since the other approach wasn't working - I'll post it at the bottom of my answer in case you want to play with that method as well.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'll try it out as I actually just run into another issue - as the window is transparent - anything that I draw on the window appears to be transparent as well, so I actually can't see the rectangle that I draw.

Comment: Another quick question Jonathan - is your function supposed to draw also on semi-transaprent Windows? I'm somehow unable to get it to draw anything on the screen. (I've set transparency to 50 for the whole window (without using a transparency color)).

Comment: Jonathan, so I also tried a window filled with color `RGB(0,0,255)`, which is then made transparent through `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`  but your function didn't draw a black rectangle. :(

Comment: Using the `UpdateLayeredWindow` method you shouldn't call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` at all, just set the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Jonathan. I tried it again and modified the code even in some places but still couldn't get it to work. :(

Comment: If you want to upload a sample project somewhere I'm happy to have a look at it for you.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'll create a single file (main.cxx) for your convenience that you'll be able to compile. I'll get back to you soon. It will take some time for me to do that.

Comment: @bodacydo You should update your question with the new information. Comments are not meant for that.

Answer (score 2):

As modern OSes use composited window systems it is not easy to just "draw on the desktop" or the front buffer as it used to be called. The transparent overlap is probably the easiest way of achieving the result you need.

I am fairly confident there is a way to get a pointer to the composited surface, but of course, all the functions you will need to do this will be largely undocumented. The best places to start will be `dwmapi.dll`, `gdi32.dll` and `opengl32.dll`

Firstly `dwmapi.dll` has some un-tagged exports but you can get name hints for them

```
ordinal : name
100, DwmpDxGetWindowSharedSurface
101, DwmpDxUpdateWindowSharedSurface
```

When OpenGL applications want to update the window, the SwapBuffers calls end up going through these two functions. There is a handle to the allocation that contains the composited surface somewhere in all of this as this handle is given to the OpenGL driver so that OpenGL application can then send a request to have its framebuffer blitted into the composited surface.

If you can open that handle (you can probably do this with [`D3DKMTLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should be able to write to the composited surface prior to it being presented to the screen.

It's been a while since I messed around with this kind of thing, but I hope this may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe, but if you want to draw to the "REAL" framebuffer then it is probably the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in hearing if there is a way to do this without cheating... Because as far as I know all of the snipping programs make a copy of your current desktop before it lets you select an area to copy.

Check out the snipping tool that comes with Windows.
%windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe
It captures the current desktops to a bitmap, displays them full screen over your current desktops, and then lets you select a portion of the screen to copy.

Other programs use similar techniques with fancier code. For example some snipping tools create a full screen transparent window over all of your desktops and then lets you draw the square area on the transparent form; however, the actual image capture is done by removing the transparent window and mapping the form to screen coordinates to capture the portion of the desktop.

There's two reasons for the trickery. First is you need to capture mouse input and prevent the underlying desktop / application from using the mouse info. Second is a canvas is required for drawing and windows doesn't expose a single canvas that encompasses all desktops.

Been years since I've done anything like this, so maybe things have changed?

Good Luck :)